# Getting error after Installing Rancher desktop and not seeing any docker images

Tags: rancher-desktop

Installed  Rancher desktop version 1.0.1 and getting this error on the "Kubernetes setting" tab.
Images tab  says: Waiting for image manager to be ready

Rancher desktop :Error Starting Kubernetes
Error: C:\Users<userid>\AppData\Local\Programs\Rancher Desktop\resources\resources\win32\bin\kubectl.exe exited with code 255

Last command run:
wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec /mnt/c/Users//AppData/Local/Programs/Rancher Desktop/resources/resources/linux/wsl-helper k3s kubeconfig

Context:
Updating kubeconfig

2022-02-04T14:05:38.370Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec wslpath -a -u C:\Users<USERID>\AppData\Local\Temp\rd-k3s-RMOHB8\k3s...
2022-02-04T14:05:39.171Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec cp /mnt/c/Users//AppData/Local/Temp/rd-k3s-RMOHB8/k3s /etc/conf.d/k3s...
2022-02-04T14:05:40.089Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec chmod 644 /etc/conf.d/k3s...
2022-02-04T14:05:40.833Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec /sbin/rc-update --update...
2022-02-04T14:05:41.695Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec /usr/local/bin/wsl-service k3s start...
2022-02-04T14:05:42.803Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec cat /proc/net/route...
2022-02-04T14:05:44.169Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec cat /proc/net/fib_trie...
2022-02-04T14:05:48.403Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec wslpath -a -u C:\Users<USERID>\AppData\Local\Programs\Rancher Desktop\resources\resources\linux\wsl-helper...
2022-02-04T14:05:49.537Z: Running command wsl --distribution rancher-desktop --exec /mnt/c/Users//AppData/Local/Programs/Rancher Desktop/resources/resources/linux/wsl-helper k3s kubeconfig...

Answer (score 10):

i solve this with delete file .kube\config in your user directory,

then restart your rancher desktop,

just like in this post
https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues/1494

Answer (score 0):

For Macbook with M3, Switching Virtualization
Virtual Machine > from EQMU to VZ
worked for me

[image]